# Determining if a UILocalNotification was fired from scheduling or user interaction

Tags: ios, cocoa, uikit, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to determine different scenarios of `UIApplication didReceiveLocalNotification:`. If a user clicks the notification the while app is inactive, I should bring them to the corresponding UI page. Otherwise, if user just opened the app without tapping a notification, I should let them stay in the UI page which they left off from.

However, there is a little problem as the `UILocalNotification` was scheduled by myself.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:scheduledAlert];
```

So every time it fired by iOS, it will call the same delegate method as the callback when I manually clicked the notification on the status bar:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification { ... }
```

I tried some tricky hack such as counting the fired times while app is inactive mode, counting 1 means iOS firing, and counting 2 means user clicked, and relative counting management code.

But I don't think this could be the best practice. I checked the iOS Messages application, which has the same functionality. If you put the app into inactive mode, such as scroll down the status bar, then it can determine the `UILocalNotification` is from your touch (and will open the text editing mode) or just you return back to the app (stay in the previous status).

I would appreciate if you guys could let me know what the best solution is here!

Answer (score 0):

I use a custom key-value pair which I set a NSMutableDictionary, which I then assign to UILocalNotification.userInfo, to tell different scenarios.

Comment: Thanks! However could you be more specific? I think in both scenario it will receive the same notification - which will contain the same dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

I check the app state so that I only handle the notification if I'm coming from the background:

```
UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
    // Your  Code Here
} else {

}
```